# PHP :: Parse strings, while iterating through an array of substrings?

Tags: php, arrays, string, parsing, substring

I'm a Java developer who is struggling to write his first PHP script.  FYI, I'm coding with PHP 8.1.2 on an Ubuntu machine.

My code has to open a log file, read the lines one-by-one, then extract a key substring based on the preamble of the string.  For example, if the log file is:

```
April 01 2020 Key Information Read :: Interesting Character #1:  Kermit the Frog
April 01 2020 Key Information Read :: Interesting Character #2:  Miss Piggy
April 01 2020 Key Information Read :: Their Best Movie:  The Muppet Movie (1979)
...many more lines...
```

Then I need a script that reads each line and extracts:

```
Kermit the Frog
Miss Piggy
The Muppet Movie (1979)
...many more items...
```

I won't know those above values before the file is read.

This problem is very solvable.  Here's my PHP code, where $str is one line of the input file:

```
    function parseThisStr($str){
            if( str_contains($str, "Interesting Character #1:  ") ){
                    $mySubstr = "Interesting Character #1:  ";
                    $tmpIndex = strpos( $str, $mySubstr );
                    $tmpIndex += strlen($mySubstr);
                    $str2 = substr( $str, $tmpIndex );
                    $str2 = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', '', $str2);   // remove newline
                    return $str2;
            }
            else if( str_contains($str, "Interesting Character #2:  ") ){
                    $mySubstr = "Interesting Character #2:  ";
                    ...copy code from above...
                    return $str2;
            else if( str_contains($str, "Their Best Movie:  ") ){
                    $mySubstr = "Their Best Movie:  ";
                    ...copy code from above...
                    return $str2;
            return $str;
    }
```

This will work... but its needlessly repetitive, right?  For each substring I am checking, I need to copy five identical lines of code.  There are about 30 substrings I need to search for; this will make my code about 150 lines longer than it needs to be.

There's got to be a way to do this with more intelligence, right?  Can't I store every to-be-searched substring in an array, maybe like this:

```
$array = array(
    1    => "Interesting Character #1:  ",
    2    => "Interesting Character #2:  ",
    3    => "Their Best Movie:  ",
    ...etc...
);
```

...and then iterate through the array, maybe like this:

```
    function parseThisStr($str){
            $array = array(
                  1    => "Kermit the Frog",
                  ...etc...
            };
            foreach( $array as &$value ){
                if( str_contains($str, $value) ){
                        $tmpIndex = strpos( $str, $value );
                        $tmpIndex += strlen($value);
                        $str2 = substr( $str, $tmpIndex );
                        $str2 = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', '', $str2);   // remove newline
                        return $str2;
                }
            return null;
            }
```

Conceptually, this should work... but I can't figure out the correct syntax.  PHP syntax is confusing to me, sadly.  Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?  Thank you.

EDIT:  I screwed up the values of `$array` in my first posting.  `$array` should have the substrings that I'll use to search the larger string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex'es will produce more clear code. For example with `preg_match`:

```
$line = 'April 01 2020 Key Information Read :: Interesting Character #1:  Kermit the Frog';
$searchTerms = ["Kermit the Frog","Miss Piggy","The Muppet Movie (1979)"];

// prepare regex with named group from terms
$delimiter = '~';
$regex = $delimiter . '(?<phrase>(' . join('|', array_map(fn($term) => preg_quote($term, $delimiter), $searchTerms)) . '))' . $delimite;

// search by regex
preg_match($regex, $line, $matches);
$foundPhrase = $matches['phrase'] ?? null;
```

Comment: I apologize; I think I screwed up the original post.  The values of "Kermit the Frog", "Miss Piggy", etc, couldn't be known before the code is run.  Therefore, the values in $array must be the key substrings that proceed these target substrings.  I've modified the original post to correct this error on my part.

Comment: You can use the same approach, just using regex like "Interesting Character #\d*: (?<phrase>[\w ]*)". Here is a good sandbox where you could do some experiments with regexps: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2):

You might use a regex with a more specific pattern:

```
\b(?:Interesting Character #\d+:|Their Best Movie:)\h+\K.+
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:Interesting Character #\d+:|Their Best Movie:)`
- `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace characters
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `.+` Match 1 or more characters

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p2czGK/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/JvrcR)

```
$re = '/\b(?:Interesting Character #\d+:|Their Best Movie:)\h+\K.+/';
$str = 'April 01 2020 Key Information Read :: Interesting Character #1:  Kermit the Frog
April 01 2020 Key Information Read :: Interesting Character #2:  Miss Piggy
April 01 2020 Key Information Read :: Their Best Movie:  The Muppet Movie (1979)
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Kermit the Frog
    [1] => Miss Piggy
    [2] => The Muppet Movie (1979)
)
```

Another pattern with a bit broader match taking the leading `::` into account and match until the first occurrence of `:`

```
::\h+[^:\r\n]+:\h+\K.+
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/izPucs/1)